# VBA - set Range using column variable

Tags: excel, vba

I entered a piece of code to find column by name and I want to use this variable later in the code.

```
ColTax = Application.Match("Tax", Sheets("DATA").Rows(1), 0)
```

However, I have a problem with updating the range below:

```
Set rng = Range("I3", Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

How do I update "I" to reflect ColTax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Cells` instead of `Range`, since `Cells` accepts a numeric column index.

```
Dim ColTax As Variant ' Application.Match can return an error, so must be a Variant
ColTax = Application.Match("Tax", Sheets("DATA").Rows(1), 0)

If IsError(ColTax) Then
    ' The match failed, so ColTax is an error, not the column number
    Exit Sub
End If

With Sheets("Data")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(3, ColTax), .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColTax).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
```

Note that `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` will throw an error if there are no visible cells. Safest would be to enclose the `Set rng` line with `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`, and then test `If not rng Is Nothing`.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = ....
On Error GoTo 0

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    ' keep processing
End If
```